Can someone find a closed form expression for the following sum involving Hermite polynomials?
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{2n}(2n)!\sqrt{2n+1}}H_{2n}(x)H_{2n}(x')$$.
This sum is very similar to the well-known summation formula: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n n!}H_{n}(x)H_{n}(x') = \sqrt{\pi}e^{\frac{1}{2}(x^2+x'^2)}\delta(x-x')$, except that there is a square root factor of 2n+1 in the sum. It would be great if a closed-form expression could be obtained in terms of a Dirac delta.

In what context did this sum arise in?

Which version of Hermite polynomials are you using, probabilist's or physiciat's?

This is an interesting problem. I imagine any closed form will come from reverse engineering the differential operator for which this is the Green’s function and corresponding Hermite functions are eigenfunctions

You can try and use some analog of Mehler's formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehler_kernel ), using for summation with respect to $n$ the presentation $$\frac1{\sqrt{2n+1}}=\frac2  {\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-(2n+1)t^2}dt$$
then use the factor $\rho=e^{-2t^2}$ in the summation formula. You probably cannot use the Mehler's formula directly, as you polynomials has the range $2n$, but you can get the analogue, applying the Fourier transform (as the original Mehler's formula can be obtained).
In the best case scenario you will get the integral representation of the sum.

@whatamidoing The context concerns pseudo-spin operators in SU(2) representation for bosonic states and trying to calculate Bell's inequality using these operators.

@SangchulLee, this is physicists' Hermite polynomial.

@Svyatoslav Thanks a lot! I got to the part where I now need to solve $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\rho/2)^{2n}}{(2n)!}H_{2n}(x)H_{2n}(x')$$, but not sure what you meant by "applying the Fourier transform (as the original Mehler's formula can be obtained)."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials , section Completeness relation, at the end of the article
